# Trying to make assembly-level sly programming language

Tags: python, assembly, sly

I'm trying to write a low-level parser using sly and python. However, when I run my code I get an error:

```
syntax error: "1", at line 1
```

The code in question is:

```
#!/bin/python3

from sly import Lexer, Parser

class LowLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = {DAT, MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL, 
              DIV, MOD, JMP, JMZ, JMN, 
              DJN, SEQ, SNE, CMP, SLT, 
              NOP, NAME, STRING, NUMBER}
    ignore = '\t '
    literals = { '=', ',', ';'}

    # Define tokens as regular expressions
    # (stored as raw strings)
    NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    STRING = r'\".*?\"'
    DAT = r'DAT'
    MOV = r'MOV'
    ADD = r'ADD'
    SUB = r'SUB'
    MUL = r'MUL'
    DIV = r'DIV'
    MOD = r'MOD'
    JMP = r'JMP'
    JMZ = r'JMZ'
    JMN = r'JMN'
    DJN = r'DJN'
    SEQ = r'SEQ'
    SNE = r'SNE'
    CMP = r'CMP'
    SLT = r'SLT'
    NOP = r'NOP'

    @_(r'\n')
    def line_count(self, t):
        self.lineno += 1

    @_(r'\[[^\[\]]*\]')
    def comment(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

    @_(r'\d+')
    def NUMBER(self, t):
        t.value = int(t.value)
        return t

    def error(self, t):
        print("error at line {}: bad character - {}".format(self.lineno, t.value[0]))
        exit(1)   

class LowParser(Parser):
    #tokens are passed from lexer to parser
    tokens = LowLexer.tokens
    precedence = (
        ('left', DAT, MOV, ADD, SUB, MUL),
        ('left', DIV, MOD, JMP, JMZ, JMN),
        ('left', DJN, SEQ, SNE, CMP, SLT),
        ('left', NOP)
        )
  
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = { }
  
    def error(self, t):
        print("syntax error: \"{}\", at line {}".format(t.value, t.lineno))
        exit(1)

    @_('')
    def statement(self, p):
        print("in here statement")
        pass
    
    @_('expr')
    def statement(self, p):
        print("in here expr")
        return (p.expr)
    
    @_('MOV NUMBER NUMBER')
    def expr(self, p):
        print("in here mov")
        return ('MOV', p.expr0, p.expr1)

    @_('NAME')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ('var', p.NAME)
  
    @_('NUMBER')
    def expr(self, p):
        print("in here number")
        return ('num', p.NUMBER)

def main():
    lexer = LowLexer()
    parser = LowParser()
    expression = "MOV 1 2"
    tree = parser.parse(lexer.tokenize(expression))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

It seemed pretty straightforward to me but from my understanding you are supposed to first define tokens, which I did, and then you have to parse them appropriate, which I think I'm not doing correctly. Does anyone know how I might go about doing this appropriately?

Comment: Found your deleted question: [Make simple pseudo terminal website in js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76060551/387194), did you solve the issue? You need to include external JS and CSS files that are in CodePen settings. I can add an answer if you undelete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current issue is with your tokenizer. Currently, it is reading your "MOV" as a NAME. Moving your definition of NAME below your instruction constants gets it past that error. Then you need to fix an issue with your "MOV NUMBER NUMBER" construct for *expr*:

```
@_('MOV NUMBER NUMBER')
def expr(self, p):
    print("in here mov")
    return ('MOV', p.expr0, p.expr1)
```

will not work because you have no parameters named *expr*. Instead you want this:

```
@_('MOV NUMBER NUMBER')
def expr(self, p):
    print("in here mov")
    return ('MOV', p.NUMBER0, p.NUMBER1)
```

Comment: I just did what you said but now it can't process more than one line of code. It simply throws an error for the next line no matter the order of the code.

Comment: Try running the code with  expression = "MOV 0 1\nADD 1 2"
It will throw an error

Comment: That is because you don't define multiple statements. Take a look at the Calc example. Your first statement will basically be a statement list that consists of either a single statement, or a statement followed by a statement list.